# Modificar css dinamicamente con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo este botón

```css
:root {
  --color-green: #00a878;
  --color-red: #fe5e41;
  --color-button: #fdffff;
  --color-black: #000;
}

.switch-button {
  display: inline-block;
}

.switch-button .switch-button__checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.switch-button .switch-button__label {
  background-color: var(--color-red);
  width: 5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.switch-button .switch-button__label:before {
  transition: .2s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: var(--color-button);
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px var(--color-black);
}

.switch-button .switch-button__checkbox:checked+.switch-button__label {
  background-color: var(--color-green);
}

.switch-button .switch-button__checkbox:checked+.switch-button__label:before {
  transform: translateX(2rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-button">
  <input type="checkbox" name="switch-button" id="switch-label" class="switch-button__checkbox">
  <label for="switch-label" class="switch-button__label"></label>
</div>
```

Que he sacado de [esta web](https://programadorwebvalencia.com/sencillo-boton-on-off-html-y-css/)

Me gustaría por un lado saber si el botón esta "Desplegado" o "Cerrado" con algún tipo de condición y de que forma puedo yo provocar mediante codigo, que ese botón se Despliegue o se cierre.

He intengado la opción:

```
$( "boton" ).addClass( "switch-button .switch-button__checkbox:checked + .switch-button__label:before" );`
```

Pero no me funciona, en mi html tengo la llamada al botón de esta forma:

```
<body class="m-0 vh-100 row justify-content-center align-items-center ">
<div class="col-auto p-5 text-center">
    <div class="switch-button" id="boton">
        <!-- Checkbox -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="switch-button" id="switch-label" class="switch-button__checkbox ">
        <!-- Botón -->
        <label for="switch-label" class="switch-button__label"></label>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Me gustaría poder saber en que estado esta el botón, (Que clase tiene activa) y activar o desactivar el botón mediante llamadas a código. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos:

- Para saber si esta "activo" o no, necesitas saber si el `<input type="checkbox"` esta [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-checked)
- Para activarlo o desactivarlo, necesitas cambiar la propiedad `checked`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const $switch = $('#switch-label');

function activate(enable) {
  $switch.prop('checked', enable);
}

function getStatus() {
  console.log($switch.prop('checked') ? 'Activado' : 'Desactivado')
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color-green: #00a878;
  --color-red: #fe5e41;
  --color-button: #fdffff;
  --color-black: #000;
}

.switch-button {
  display: inline-block;
}

.switch-button .switch-button__checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.switch-button .switch-button__label {
  background-color: var(--color-red);
  width: 5rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.switch-button .switch-button__label:before {
  transition: .2s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: var(--color-button);
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px var(--color-black);
}

.switch-button .switch-button__checkbox:checked+.switch-button__label {
  background-color: var(--color-green);
}

.switch-button .switch-button__checkbox:checked+.switch-button__label:before {
  transform: translateX(2rem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="switch-button">
  <input type="checkbox" name="switch-button" id="switch-label" class="switch-button__checkbox">
  <label for="switch-label" class="switch-button__label"></label>
</div>
<br/>
<button onclick="activate(true)">Activar</button>
<button onclick="activate(false)">Desactivar</button>
<button onclick="getStatus()">Obtener estado</button>
```